# initializing an openni::VideoStream object without kinect plugged in

Tags: c++, video-streaming, kinect, openni, depth

I'm using openNI2 in order to capture kinect depth data.

in order to initialize m_depth, i have to use some methods of the class openni::VideoStream, like this:

```
openni::VideoStream m_depth;
openni::Device device;
const char* device_uri;
openni::Status ret;
device_uri = openni::ANY_DEVICE;
ret = openni::STATUS_OK;        
ret = openni::OpenNI::initialize();
ret = device.open(device_uri);
ret = m_depth.create(device, openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
```

The is that i want to initialize the object "**m_depth**" without the kinect plugged in. of course i can't because the methods of this class, like "**m_depth.create**" doesn't work.

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an .ONI file (a dummy could work) to init
Quoting the OpenNI2 documentation

> Later, this file can be used to initialize a file Device, and used to
>   play back the same data that was recorded.
>
> Opening a file device is done by passing its path as the uri to the
>   Device::open() method

So, you can change this line

```
device_uri = openni::ANY_DEVICE;
```

to the path of the dummy ONI file...

I don't think in OpenNI2 there is another way to create a depth stream, and actually it doesn't make sense to create a stream without a camera unless you want to use the coordinate converter class...

In openni 1.x you can try using mockdepth (though I didn't managed to make it work correctly)